# Непонятная ошибка в скрипте для плавной прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/d83tocz1/

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () { 
  var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
  var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  if($.browser.safari){
    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
  }else{
    $('html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
  }
  return false;
})
```

```css
header{
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}

section{
  height: 700px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
<a href='#go'>scrollll too</a>

</header>


<section>
  <a name='go'></a>
</section>
```

Добрый день, есть данный скрипт но выдает ошибку по непонятным мне причинам

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт ? Cannot read property 'top' of undefined ?

Comment: думаю проблема в том что вы указали  <a name='go'></a>, для работы якоря должен быть ID    <a id='go'></a>

Comment: у вас `elementClick` это текстовая строка а не элемент

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в селекторе. `$(this).attr("href")` возвращает строку `#go`, и функция `$('#go')` пытается найти элемент с атрибутом id, а такого нет. Для исправления ошибки, уберем символ `#` и перепишем селектор для выбора элемента `a` c атрибутом `name`.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function () { 
  var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
  var destination =$('a[name="'+elementClick.replace('#', '')+'"]').offset().top;
  if($.browser.safari){
    $('body').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
  }else{
    $('html').animate( { scrollTop: destination }, 1100 );
  }
  return false;
})
```